# How to get data from custom shipping method in javascript Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, javascript

I am making a magento 2 module, and I had to create a custom shipping method  but I am not able to get the data of fields in the checkout page :

This is a part of my system.xml file

```
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

            <group id="my_shipping_methode" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

                <field id="myfield" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
```

and this is the constructor of my module :

```
<?php namespace A\B\Model\Carrier; 
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Shipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'my_shipping_methode';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $myfield = 'test';
```

And this is part of my javascript file I call in the checkout to get the code of the shipping method :

```
this.selectedMethod = ko.computed(function() {
            var method = quote.shippingMethod();
            var selectedMethod = method != null ? method.method_code : null;
```

I tried to do the same for my field but it didn't work

```
var myfield = method != null ? method.method_myfield : null;
```

Please help I am lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!

This is how I did it :

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\Simpleshipping\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SampleConfigProvider
 */
class SampleConfigProvider extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper implements ConfigProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $postTest = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/simpleshipping/myfield',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


        return [
            'foo' => [
                'bar' => $postTest,
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

In my javascript :

```
getSampleTotal: function () {;
            return window.checkoutConfig.foo.bar;
        }
```

In my template :

```
<div class="component-wrapper">
        <p data-bind="html: getSampleTotal()"></p>
    </div>
```

in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Mageplaza_Simpleshipping_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Mageplaza\Simpleshipping\Model\SampleConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

system.xml

```
 <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

            <group id="simpleshipping" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

                <field id="myfield" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your protected code should be equal to the name of your `system.xml` group configuration.  Instead of **`protected $_code = 'thecode';`**, It should be:

```
protected $_code = 'my_shipping_methode';
```

Comment: Actually I changed the values of my params just to give the example of the situation i am into, and forgot about that , but still it's not really the problem as it's coorect in my code. I fixed that in my question thanks for pointing that.

Comment: great. but why you need a javascript? , I think using the class `Shipping Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest` your shipping method will automatically be added in checkout

Comment: Actually the shipping is added correctly and I can see it but The problem is I want to get the value of one of its fields I added my self (myfield) and send it to javascript to do some stuf with it in the checkout page

Comment: what is your goal for this? what is your expected output?

Comment: When the customer choose the shipping methode in a client shop I show a map created in the back office (some other logic) and one of its parametrs is an ID different for each one using the module the ID is made by some other services not me.

Comment: with that much info, I think it is better to override the checkout layout including the shipping-method-item renderer, from there you can do whatever you need. or the other way , check on how to display custom elements on checkout using Layoutprocessor

Comment: Ok thanks I will keep looking for a workaround I am already lost so I don't want to do it overriding things I am new to magento so I don't think that I will be able to do it anyway for now.